# Why is my test.check test using inputs smaller than the generator?

Tags: testing, clojure, property-based-testing, test.check

I've implemented my own version of `index-of`. It takes two strings and returns the index where the second string is found in the first. In use, it seems to work fine, but it's failing the test.check property test. The weird thing is test.check says it fails at values like "0bU", but I have it set so the smallest input is 100 characters. Why is it using inputs smaller than what I've told it to use?

I wrote my own generator using `gen/fmap` and it looks correct when I call it using `gen/sample`.

The code:

```
(defn gen-alphanumeric   "A generator that accepts a minimum and maximum string length" [min max]   
    (gen/fmap str/join (gen/vector gen/char-alphanumeric min max)))

(defspec indexof-functionality-test   
  (prop/for-all [s1 (gen-alphanumeric 100 200)
                 begin gen/nat 80]
    (let [end (+ begin 10)
          s2 (subs s1 begin end)]
      (= (str/index-of s1 s2) (cp-str/indexof s1 s2)))))
```

The output from `lein test`

> FAIL in (indexof-functionality-test) (string_test.clj:57) expected:
> {:result true}   actual: {:shrunk {:total-nodes-visited 11, :depth 4,
> :pass? false, :result false, :result-data nil, :time-shrinking-ms 2,
> :smallest ["240"]}, :failed-after-ms 0, :num-tests 4, :seed
> 1676231835751, :fail ["n5n0"], :result false, :result-data nil,
> :failing-size 3, :pass? false, :test-var "indexof-functionality-test"}

EDIT:

My cp-str/indexof

```
(defn indexof
  "given two strings, returns the index where sb begins in sa. Nil if not found"
  ([sa sb]
   (indexof sa sb 0))
  ([sa sb i]
   (let [sa-len (count sa)
         sb-len (count sb)]
     (cond
       (>= 0 sa-len) nil
       (>= 0 sb-len) nil
       ; this is hit when element not found
       (> (+ i sb-len) sa-len) nil
       (= (subs sa i (+ i sb-len)) sb) i
       :else (indexof sa sb (inc i))))))
```

EDIT2: It fails on one computer and passes on another. Those three methods are identical on the two computers.

Comment: I can't completely run your code because you haven't provided `cp-str/index-of`, and when I run a degenerate version (that obviously won't fail on the exact same examples that yours does), I don't see it generating small strings.

Comment: @gfredericks - I added in `cp-str/indexof`

Comment: I also wasn't able to reproduce generating short strings (even with the same seed). Instead, I run into some StringIndexOutOfBoundsException, when I increased the number of the tests (200+). I guess `begin gen/nat 80` (80 is discarded) is generating too high numbers and you should use something like `gen/such-that`.

Comment: or `(gen/resize 80 gen/nat)`

Comment: @gfredericks I played around with this and test passes on one computer and fails on another. Ideas?

Comment: I have tried to make it more specific here:

https://github.com/gfredericks/stack-overflow-75429881

When you run that `go.sh` script, do you get different results on two different computers? If so, I think you could report that as a general clojure issue, and/or debug it further to isolate it to a much smaller piece of code that has inconsistent behavior.

Comment: @gfredericks Thanks a lot! For some reason the tests now pass on both computers. I am perplexed, but I guess that is good enough.